# Is Custom Audience creation exposed by the FaceBook Marketing API?

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-marketing-api

I can't find any documentation or other examples of how to do this from the API (specifically the Python API). All the documentation refers to uploading a custom audience .csv via Power Editor or the Ad Manager. Has anyone else come across this?

Answer (score 1):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/custom-audience
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/custom-audience/users/

```
from facebookads.objects import CustomAudience

audience = CustomAudience(parent_id='act_<AD_ACCOUNT_ID>')
audience[CustomAudience.Field.subtype] = CustomAudience.Subtype.custom
audience[CustomAudience.Field.name] = 'My new CA'
audience[CustomAudience.Field.description] = 'People who bought on my website'

audience.remote_create()
```

Then:

```
from facebookads.objects import CustomAudience

audience = CustomAudience('<CUSTOM_AUDIENCE_ID>')
users = ['test1@example.com', 'test2@example.com', 'test3@example.com']

audience.add_users(CustomAudience.Schema.email_hash, users)
```

Comment: So it just takes the users list as a list? Interesting.
Thanks!